# Как правильно оформить приложение?

Tags: приложение, пунктуация

Какой знак должен стоять в этих случаях?

> 1. Навестили семейную пару ветеранов Великой Отечественной войны – Петровых
>    Ивана Семеновича и Надежду Васильевну.
> 2. Навестили семью Петровых – ветеранов Великой Отечественной войны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Навестили семейную пару ветеранов Великой Отечественной войны – Петровых Ивана Семеновича и Надежду Васильевну. - Тире перед однородными членами корректно.
2. Навестили семью Петровых – ветеранов Великой Отечественной войны. - Возможно, но лучше вместо тире запятую.